# C# работа с Excel

Tags: c#, excel

Стоит задача у меня организовать чтение из таблицы Excel (всего-лишь 2 колонки скачать). Вроде бы все просто:

```
            OleDbConnection con = null;
            var dsLocal = new DataSet("ExcelDataSet");
            var listTables = new ArrayList();
            var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            var command = new OleDbCommand();

            string ExcelDriver = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0";

var strConnection =
                    String.Format("Provider={1};Data Source='{0}';Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\"",
                        path, ExcelDriver);
                con = new OleDbConnection(strConnection);

                con.Open();
```

Дальше уже чтение последней строки дело не заходит - ошибка

> The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

Гугл мне посдказывал установить обновления/расширения для офиса (например [это](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3)), но результат тот же.

Может кто сталкивался с таким? Я пробовал разные провайдеры, но не помогает.

**UPD:**
Сейчас я сделал чтение из Екселя как здесь [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18993735/how-to-read-single-excel-cell-value). Но мне интеересно разобраться с этой ситуацией

Comment: Посмотрите как сделано в [этом](http://wladm.narod.ru/C_Sharp/comexcel.html) примере.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Установите [Microsoft ACE Provider](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) той же битности, что и ваша ОС. Приложение должно работать в 32-битном режиме. Если ваш код работает под IIS'ом, поставьте в настройках апп пула `Enable 32-bit Applications = true`.

**UPD**

Как крайний вариант, можете попробовать использовать стороннюю библиотеку, которая не требует ACE провайдера, например, [NPOI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NPOI/).

Comment: Я поставил. Получается у меня винда 7 64-битная, а офис - 32-битный. Результат не изменился.

Comment: @LeonardBertone если честно, верится с трудом :). Должно работать как часы.

Comment: @LeonardBertone обновил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать  пакет [ExcelDataReader](https://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/) работал с ним, проблем не возникало