# С#: драйвер для работы с Excel

Tags: c#, excel, ole, oledb

Я пытаюсь прочитать данные из Excel с помощью OleDbConnection.
Проблема в том, что какой бы я провайдер не указывал в строке подключения, я получаю ошибку, что такой провайдер не установлен.

Я устанавливал Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable но не помогло.
Код:

```
 "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.14.0; Extended Properties=\"Excel 14.0; HDR=Yes\";Data Source={0};",
                    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0; HDR=Yes\"; Data Source={0};",
                    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0; HDR=Yes\";Data Source={0};",
                    "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Extended Properties\"Excel 8.0; HDR=Yes\";Data Source={0};",

Data Source = "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Bulk1.xlsx";
```

**Я вижу тут 2 решения - как-то(?) установить драйвер, либо как-то(?) искать провайдер, который стоит у меня на машине.**

Помогите, пожалуйста с этой проблемой.

Используемое ПО: Windows 7 x64, Microsoft Office 2010 x32

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [C# работа с Excel](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/c-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81-excel)

Comment: Переделал все на OpenXML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я вам уже отвечал в двух предыдущих ответах:

1. Должен стоять Microsoft ACE Provider 2010 той же битности, что и ваша ОС. Если вы читаете xslx, то строка подключения должна содержать `Excel 12.0` в Extended Properties.
2. Приложение должно работать в 32-битном режиме.
3. JET провайдер поддерживает только файлы формата младше 2007. Чтение
   xlsx он не поддерживает.

Как крайний вариант, можете попробовать использовать стороннюю библиотеку, которая не требует ACE провайдера, например, [NPOI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NPOI/).

Comment: я пробовал установить Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable 64 но нельзя - ругается что офис 32ух битный. Как-то можно выйти из положения?

Comment: @LeonardBertone а, у вас еще и Офис стоит... Попробуйте тогда 32-битный поставить.

Comment: я поставил 32ух битный, но результата это не принесло

Comment: @LeonardBertone приложение у вас скомпилировано как 32-битное?

Comment: да, в Configuration Managerя указал архитектуру 32х у проекта, а у остальных проектов в этом решении оставил "Acu CPU". или може твезде менять надо?

Comment: 32x -> 86x; все решение же осталось в "Any CPU"

Comment: Даже если все Решение перевести на х86, ошибка остается. Может еще что-то нудно сделать, галочку какую поставить где-то??

Comment: @LeonardBertone больше ничего в голову не приходит. Мне всех этих шагов было достаточно.

Comment: А может этому мешать установленный Linq (MS Office 2013) ?

Comment: @LeonardBertone по идее не должен, но по факту черт его знает.

Comment: В общем, я так понял у меня не работало из-за того, что я использовал другую программу для запуска своей. Мой тот же самый код в консольном приложении с Вашими советами РАБОТАЕТ.

Comment: @LeonardBertone ну вы даете :).